# FindItems operation missing from EWS since upgrade to 2013

Tags: exchangewebservices

This has worked fine for years, but since ugprading to Exchange 2013 by our operations department (and possible other tweaks that I don't know about), the FindItems method is missing from EWS. I can still find it via the managed API of course (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll version 15), but calling it gives a 501 Not Implemented error. When I browse https:///ews/Services.wsdl the method is indeed nowhere to be found.

When I look at MS' documentation, I also see that the method is not there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . Weird, right?

What's absurd is that we have a service running i production that calls this method many times per day without logging any errors, but I cannot find the method myself. I have tried logging on to the server that the service is running on with the same user that the service runs from, and I still can't find the FindItems method in the WSDL.

Are there any other ways to "search" a user's calendar via EWS?

Answer (score 0):

FindItems is the EWS Managed API method ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)).

FindItem (not plural, no "s") is the equivalent EWS operation ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566107(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566107%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)). I'm seeing FindItemSoapIn and FindItemSoapOut in my Services.wsdl. If you take out the "s", can you find it then?

Comment: I see your point, but it doesn't help me much. I see I misunderstood how the managed API works - I thought it was a direct proxy to the EWS service. What happens when I call the FindItems method is that I get a 501 Not Implemented error, which I then concluded was beacuse the FindItems operation is not present in EWS. I'm trying to chase down why I get the 501 error.

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on? Are you able to make other EWS calls successfully or do all of them give a 501 error?

Comment: Got any solution, I am also getting 501?